# Sitemap.xml at root location - Tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1, dxa, sdl-tridion, dxa-1.7

We are using DXA 1.7 and created a sitemap page. When I deploy the page it deploys to broker database. I need to drop the generated sitemap.xml file to the root location of my project. What are the options I have? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

If you create the page in the root SG, the sitemap.xml will be available in your rootURL/sitemap.xml. The crawler should be able to browse the site to pick it up, without any modifications or customization.

If for some reason, you need the file to be physically available on the root on the project (on the filesystem), you have a few options.

- Use a combination of symlinks (to the root of the website) and
  replication software (to copy to other servers) to copy the file to
  the filesystem upon publishing, based on XML extension.
- Create a controller to download the file from the broker and store it
  in the application root. It needs to be protected with proper
  security. You can call the controller during post-publish (deployer extension or event system)
- Statically include the file in the root of your project, if it does
  not change frequently.
- You can also publish the file as a binary and ask your crawler to
  look up the BinaryData/tcmid/ folder instead of the website root.

Hope it helps!